# Blackberry: PhoneListener does not persist

Tags: blackberry

I am using Blackberry curve 9300.

I made an app in which I have added PhoneListener that does something every time an outgoing call starts. I have added SystemListener and SystemListener2 so that the listener gets added every time the phone powerUp(), reset() or fastReset(). And I have made sure that the app gets started at system startup too. The app works fine.

Now, the problem is that if I keep the phone idle for a while (say a couple of hours) and start using again, the PhoneListener stops working. It no longer detects an outgoing call.

It seems that the PhoneListener gets removed if you keep the phone idle for a while. What exactly happens during that time that removes the PhoneListener and how to handle that?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit strange situation. What would I do in this case:

1. Implement a method in PhoneListener, let say `public void nudge()`. This method logs the current state of the object along with the current time. All log info should be written to EventLogger instance and/or text file on the device filesystem.
2. Implement a TimerTask that controls the integrity on PhoneListener object. It just checks the object presence (!=null, and invokes `nudge()` method). Please note that if you set short recurrence period, then logging to a text file on media card is preffered. Writing a huge amount of data to EventLogger, that uses internal device memory, may hang your device or even brick it.
3. Inspect log file.

It may give you a clue what is going on.